# C++ неявное приведение типов

Tags: c++

подскажите пожалуйста, как в компилятор С++ разрешает проблему неявного привидения типов. В частности интересует вопрос: почему в первом случае компилятор сможет построить цепочку преобразований, а во втором нет? Или подскажите где можно об этом почитать.

1

```
struct String 
{
    operator int();
};
int main()
{
    String s("Hello");
    if (s) {}
}
```

2

```
struct String
{
    operator String2();
};

struct String2
{
    operator bool();
};
int main()
{
    String s("Hello");
    if (s) {}
}
```

Comment: можете более полный КОМПИЛИРУЕМЫЙ пример. А то сдесь дыры, которые не позволяют сказать в чем у вас проблема

Comment: или вы хотите узнать почему в `if` `String` не привелся к `String2`, который может приводится к `bool`? Если так, то: компилятор не может знать, что вы хотите (чтобы `String` привелся к `String2`), для этого нужно явно это указать. К примеру у вас может быть оператор приведения к `String3`, который тоже приводится к `bool` - какой тогда компилятору выбирать? Почему работает первый вариант: потому что в `if` явно требуется преобразование к `bool` (который является `int` по сути).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, спасибо, именно в этом и был вопрос.

Comment: Scala, вроде, более настойчива в неявных преобразованиях.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В стандарте C++ описаны несколько последовательностей неявного конвертирования, которые могут случаться в программах ([[over.best.ics]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics)). Ваш случай описан в [[over.ics.user]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.user), в котором говорится, что определённая пользователем функция конвертирования, может использоваться лишь один раз во всей последовательности. Т.е. последовательность, которая содержит использование переопределённого оператора преобразования, может содержать не более двух *стандартных преобразований* и лишь одно преобразование определённое пользователем.

Ваш первый случай:

1. Конвертировать `s` в `int` - определённое пользователем преобразование.
2. Конвертировать `int` в `bool` — стандартное преобразование.

Т.е. всё нормально, не более одного пользовательского преобразования и не более 2-х стандартных преобразований.

Ваш второй случай (гипотетически):

1. Конвертировать `s` в `String2` - определённое пользователем преобразование.
2. Конвертировать `String2` в `bool` - определённое пользователем преобразование.

В данной цепочке получаются 2 пользовательских преобразования, что запрещено стандартом.

P.S. в обоих случаях есть ещё стандартное преобразование (identity), которое идёт первым. Но это роли не играет.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите узнать почему в `if` `String` не привелся к `String2`, который может приводится к `bool`? Если так, то: компилятор не может знать, что вы хотите (чтобы `String` привелся к `String2`), для этого нужно явно это указать. К примеру у вас может быть оператор приведения к `String3`, который тоже приводится к `bool` - какой тогда компилятору выбирать? Почему работает первый вариант: потому что в `if` явно требуется преобразование к `bool` (который является по сути числовым типом, как, например `int`).

Comment: @ixSci я специально добавил `по сути`. Согласен, не слишком кошерное варыжение получилось, но мной имелось ввиду, что это такой же числовой тип, с той лишь разницей, что любая цифра, кроме ноля автоматом приводится к 1 в `bool`. А так это точно такой же числовой тип.